# OpenJDK 14.0.1 gives "the switch expression does not cover all possible input values"

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, javac

Using OpenJDK 14.0.1

```
public class Example {
    private String test(final ExampleEnum ee) {
        return switch (ee) {
            case Value -> null;
        };
    }
}
```

```
public enum ExampleEnum {

    Value;

    public enum InnerEnum {
    }

}
```

Compilation fails with "the switch expression does not cover all possible input values". If I remove `InnerEnum` from `ExampleEnum` the code compiles. Why does the presence of this inner enum cause the switch expression to fail? Is there a logical explanation or a compiler bug?

Comment: You might want to check https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8243548

Comment: @Progman that appears to be the same and confirms that this is a compiler bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need add default case, like this:

```
public class Example {
private String test(final ExampleEnum ee) {
    return switch (ee) {
        case Value -> null;
        default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value");
    };
}
```